# Microsoft Office 2010 Reinstall, Pen Input No Longer Works

Tags: microsoft-office, tablet

Earlier today I upgraded to Office 13, found it was VERY problematic, so I uninstalled in and reinstalled office 2010. Now, in OneNote, Word, PowerPoint, etc... I can no longer use pen input with my Tablet PC. The pen and eraser worked great before the uninstall, but here is my toolbar in OneNote now.

[image]

Moving the pen close to the screen, as if I were going to use it, gives me this error from OneNote:

[image]

Also, Windows Journal can no longer start:

[image]

The OS itself can still use the pen as it did before.

Any idea on how I can correct this issue?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a registry problem.

Save the registry data below as a `.reg` file, then double click it to have Regedit apply this registry fix. Once the file has been run, reboot your computer and open up office:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{7F429620-16D1-471E-A81A-114992148034}]
@="wisptis"
"RunAs"="Interactive User"
"LaunchPermission"=hex:01,00,14,80,64,00,00,00,74,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,30,00,\
  00,00,02,00,1c,00,01,00,00,00,11,00,14,00,04,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  10,00,10,00,00,02,00,34,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,18,00,1f,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,\
  00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,00,14,00,0b,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,01,00,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01,02,\
  00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00
```

I would recommend making a backup of your current registry file before applying this fix, in case anything goes wrong.

I also cannot be responsible if any part of your registry is damaged.